# Document Schema in MongoDB efficiency

Tags: mongodb, search

In mongoDb I can store a object in several different ways.
First way :

```
   {
    "user_characteristics_age" : 4,
    "user_characteristics_weight" : 34,
    "user_location_city" : "Paris",
    "user_location_country" : "France"
    }
```

Second way :

```
 {
"user" : 
  {
    "characteristics" : 
     {
       "age" : 4,
       "weight" : 34,
     },

    "location" : 
     {
       "city" : "Paris",
       "country" : "France"
     }
  }
}
```

In my case I have 3 millions documents in my collection. And the documents are quite complex.
My goal is to have the most efficient database to query on some fields.
Which way would be the best ?

Comment: Try with indexing concept. ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: i would prefer cause of sagregation

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index on both scenarios, so they are comparable.  It would be an advantage to use the second way if you are going to be creating a system the works with this database and you want to deal in Objects.  Also if you ever wanted to see if a document contains a location you could issue a query such as

```
db.user.find({"location":{$exists:true}})
```